# Get nearly locations by query in Android using Geocoder?

Tags: android, google-maps, google-geocoder

I want to implement search suggestions similar to Google Maps ones.
I use this code to archive this:

```
List<Address> searchResults = new ArrayList<>();

        Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(context, context.getResources().getConfiguration().locale);
        List<Address> addresses = null;

        try {
            addresses = geocoder.getFromLocationName(query, count);

            for (Address address : addresses) {
                if (address.getMaxAddressLineIndex() > 0) {
                    searchResults.add(address);
                }
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            return Collections.emptyList();
        }

        return searchResults;
```

But It seems, that It outputs locations from all over the world, sorted in a random order. What can I do to get results related with current location?

Comment: the geocoder is not for getting places around a location. Geolocation is used for resolving a location (lat/lng) from an address. you want the Places API

Comment: Places API is not free. I need some free api.

Comment: places API is free its in google play services. https://developers.google.com/places/android-api/signup

Comment: https://developers.google.com/maps/pricing-and-plans/ It says that I should pay some money for using it. Correct me please if I misunderstand something.

Comment: please read the link i provided, you get a free limit

Comment: I've read it. And found out that I need to Get an Android API key. And to get an Android API key I should create a project in google developers console. And to enable some apis I need to pay.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/92418/discussion-between-sem-gnil-and-tyczj).

Comment: you do not have to pay, you may have to register a credit card but you have a free allotment of requests. There is no 100% unlimited free API to use so you have no choice

Comment: if you continued reading you would find this `Note that billing is enabled at the project level, not the API level. You will not be charged for use of the Google Places API for Android. However, once you enable billing for a given project, then all activated, billable APIs in that project will be billed, based on your project's usage.`